# Finding a subgroup of an abelian group that is isomorphic to Z

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

The question: If *G* is an abelian group and f is a surjective homomorphism from *G* to *Z* with kernel *K*, prove that *G* has a subgroup *H* such that *H* is isomorphic to *Z*.

By the first isomorphism theorem I know that *G*/*K* is isomorphic to *Z* (as *Z* is the image of f). So I figure I just have to find an *H* that is isomorphic to *G*/*K*, and I'm good (thanks to the transitivity of isomorphisms).

Comment: More interestingly, $G$ must have $\mathbb Z$ as a direct factor, at least when $G$ is finitely generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Hint:* You only need to prove that $G$ contains an element of infinite order.

Solution:

> If $\phi:G \to \mathbb Z$ is a surjective homomorphism, take $g \in G$ such that $\phi(g)=1$.

Comment: $K$ is a red herring.